# Using date variables in Excel formulas in VBA

Tags: vba, variables, excel

I'm trying to find the days between two dates.  For example in cell C2 I have 1/1/2014, and in C3 I have 12/31/2014.  If I use the DATEDIF formula in C4 I get the correct answer of 364 days.  However, I'm trying use only variables in a Macros. Currently I have:

```
Sub dates()


Dim NumDays As Integer
Dim StartDate, EndDate As Date

StartDate = Cells(2, 3)
EndDate = Cells(3, 3)
Range("C4").FormulaR1C1 = "=DATEDIF('" & StartDate & "','" & EndDate & "',""d"")"

End sub
```

This gives me the error: "Run-time error '1004':  Application-defined or object-defined error"

Any idea on how I can fix this?  Thank you.

Comment: You could just do `"=" & StartDate & "-" & EndDate`. This will return the number of days difference between two date values.

Comment: @Pnuts is right that StartDate was typed a variant without specifying As Date.  I've updated my answer with that edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the quotes around the date values.  Remove the single quotes and it will treat them like proper date values. Essentially, #1/1/2014# is not the same as '#1/1/2014#' to the function.

```
Sub dates()


Dim NumDays As Integer
Dim StartDate as Date, EndDate As Date

StartDate = Cells(2, 3)
EndDate = Cells(3, 3)
Range("C4").FormulaR1C1 = "=DATEDIF(" & StartDate & "," & EndDate & ",""d"")"

End sub
```

Comment: @pnuts the doublequotes exist to properly encapsulate portions of the string he is creating, which comes out for example to =DateDif(#1/1/2014#,#8/1/2014#,"d")  'note that the quotes are only required for his interval choice, d

Comment: @JimmySmith Oh well either works for me I don't mind really just confused.

Comment: @BradyK it's the difference between do you want a formula in that column or do you want a value?  The question implied he wanted a formula in the column, but there is nothing wrong with your syntax at all.

Comment: @JimmySmith either way it's only one answer. No need to worry about  which is better. I think the important thing to note here is the Microsoft doesn't support the method used in yours any longer.

Comment: @JimmySmith What do you mean? I could only locate [this](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/mac-excel-help/datedif-function-HA102927601.aspx) from Microsoft on `DATEDIF()` and note that it points out this is for compatibility with Lotus 1-2-3.... But if I look up `DateDiff()` I get [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5xbyt6f(v=vs.90).aspx) page. I'm not trying to be picky but I can't find support for `DATEDIF()` easily FROM Microsoft. IMO that means maybe I should avoid it.

Answer (score 2):

The use of `DATEDIF()` is actually discouraged as it is an old formula. Instead there is a DateDiff function built into vba. What you would do instead is:

```
Range("C4").Value = DateDiff("d", StartDate, EndDate)
```

[Here](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/datediff.php) is an explanation of the DateDiff function. I suggest you read it.

Comment: This doesn't allow you to place the formula into the cell, but maybe that wasn't the original need.

Comment: I know it doesn't. The original need was to use macros to accomplish this. Plus (at least for me) I can't actually use a `DATEDIF` formula for some reason.

Comment: I gotcha.  I answered why you couldn't below.

Comment: No I mean I literally cannot type `=DATEDIF(...)` for some reason. I get an error in Excel. My solution solves the problem above.

Comment: Brady DATEDIF() was last documented in like 2000 and Microsoft discourages people from using it..It doesn't get intelli-sense etc but should work! Try `=DATEDIF(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY()),DAY(TODAY())),DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY()),DAY(TODAY()+2)),"d")`

Comment: My solution doesn't use that. It's a method built into vba `DateDiff` not `DATEDIF` I don't really want to argue about the solution though.

Comment: @vba4all I've never seen where it's discouraged?  I use it in some VB6 desktop apps and never had any issues.  Granted there are differences between the order of parameters in the 2 languages, but I never read that.

Comment: @BradyK I am not arguing - I am just saying that the user's problem was with using the `DATEDIF()` worksheet function - your solution if fine but a complete answer worth an upvote and acceptance should explain WHY the other one didn't work and what's a better alternative. Think of future visitors.

Comment: @vba4all Sorry I guess I misread what you were saying. I didn't know `DATEDIF()` was discouraged from use. I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: @JimmySmith anything Microsoft withdraws documentation from usually becomes obsolete within the next couple of years. Very rarely they admit they were wrong or have made a bug :P

Comment: @vba4all Fyi when I copied the formula you provided above I got a `#NAME?` error.

Comment: @vba4all Oh I know there's bugs galore in some of the "Classic" stuff I work on, but just saying I've never experienced issues with it and actually need to know what those are because it makes me nervous haha

Answer (score 1):

I think that will do what you want.

```
Sub dates()


Dim NumDays As Integer
Dim StartDate, EndDate As Date

StartDate = Cells(2, 3)
EndDate = Cells(3, 3)
NumDays = EndDate - StartDate
Range("C4").Value = NumDays

End Sub
```

Comment: `Range("C4") = Cells(3, 3).Value - Cells(2, 3).Value`

Answer (score -1):

You are using the `.FormulaR1C1` property.  If you switch to the `.Formula` property it should work.